# Dataset for Hadoop Dev environment?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am learning hadoop. I want to understand how dataset/database is setup for environments like Dev, Test and Pre-prod. 
Of course in PROD environment we will be dealing with Terabytes of data, but having the same replica of tera bytes of data to other environments, i dont think it is possible.

For other environments how the datasets are replicated? only certain portions of data will be loaded and used in these non prod environments? if so how it is done?

Comment: You *could* have terabytes of data in all environments, but you'd really be wasting space on Dev and Test. My thoughts are that Dev can have whatever fake data you want, structured or not, Test has data that looks realistic to what will be in Prod - maybe a sample backup of historical data, and then Prod has the real, live, data of your systems.

Answer (score 0):

How it is replicated, basically the concept of hdfs relevant to namenodes and datanodrs should give you some research. When you create a new file it goes to name node which updated the metadata and give you a blank block id  once you write it finds the nearest datanodes base on the rack location. It replicates to the first datanodes, once its done replicating. Datanode first will replicate it to the next second then thirds and so fourth. It basically just re0licate on the very first node and the hdfs framework will handle the next preceedi g replication